# SQL SELECT statement filtering with 3 subquery joins

Tags: mysql

I realize this might not be an efficient select, but it works for now...mostly.  The problem I'm having is that if values aren't submitted for both "iminutes" and "dminutes"... I get no data.  I think if they both returned a value of "0" it would resolve this problem, but not sure how to get them to do that.  Suggestions?

```
SELECT user,total.tuser_id, total.tminutes, 
    total.tminutes-indirect.iminutes AS itminutes, total.tminutes-direct.dminutes AS dtminutes

FROM

(SELECT U.user_name AS user,U.user_id AS tuser_id, SUM(M.minutes) AS tminutes
    From summary S
    JOIN users U ON U.user_id = S.user_id
    JOIN tasks TA ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
    JOIN tcompleted TC ON TC.tcompleted_id = S.tcompleted_id
    JOIN minutes M ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
    JOIN hour_interval H ON H.hourinterval_id = S.hourinterval_id
    WHERE DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
    AND TIME(submit_date) BETWEEN '00:00:01' and '23:59:59'
    GROUP BY U.user_id) total
JOIN
    (SELECT U.user_id AS iuser_id, SUM(M.minutes) AS iminutes
    FROM summary S
    JOIN users U 
    ON U.user_id = S.user_id
    JOIN minutes M 
    ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
    JOIN tasks TA 
    ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
    WHERE TA.task_type='indirect'
    AND DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
    AND TIME(submit_date) BETWEEN '00:00:01' and '23:59:59'
    GROUP BY U.user_id) AS indirect

ON  total.tuser_id = indirect.iuser_id
JOIN  
    (SELECT U.user_id AS duser_id, SUM(M.minutes) AS dminutes
    FROM summary S
    JOIN users U 
    ON U.user_id = S.user_id
    JOIN minutes M 
    ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
    JOIN tasks TA 
    ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
    WHERE TA.task_type='direct'
    AND DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
    AND TIME(submit_date) BETWEEN '00:00:01' and '23:59:59'
    GROUP BY U.user_id) AS direct

ON  total.tuser_id = direct.duser_id

ORDER BY total.tuser_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COALESCE` will return the first non-null value provided.

```
total.tminutes-COALESCE(indirect.iminutes, 0)
```

`COALESCE` here will return 0 when iminutes is NULL. You can do the same for dminutes.

You may check the MySQL Reference Manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.  As it will run into non-null values.  Basically,  it has a value or I need it to return a "0".

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your comment, `COALESCE` will return 0 if iminutes is NULL or iminutes itself if it is non-null. As a reminder, 0 != NULL.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are correct! :)  I'm going to go about this a different way and just do totals of each and getting rid of the subtraction, as I don't need it.  Thank you!